# How to drop multiple rows of a pandas df at once?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 198 rows and 60 columns. I need to delete about 20 of these rows, is there any way to do this quickly?

df.drop would not allow me to

Comment: Just use `df.iloc`.

Comment: so df.iloc.drop([....]) ?

Comment: No, the `iloc` selects the rows you want. Selecting and dropping is the kinda same thing! If you select the rows you want, you are actually dropping the rows you do not want. So, by using `iloc` you can select the rows you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
data = np.random.randint(100, size=(10,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Before using df.drop():

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  87  36  28  25  10  28  99  54  45  36
1  96  25  64  30  47  60  65  69  78  40
2  64  29  65  49  50  99  11  89  52  33
3  96  68  98  41  37  94  21  90  74  68
4  87  23  67  50  76  85  63  37  91  71
5  50   4  60  62  72  76  61  11  93  30
6  21  18  62  34  15  72  85  31  62  66
7  57  18  40  25  10  30  35  62  73  43
8   1  89  75  25  84  11  82  36  98  58
9  78  49  46  52   8  84   2  29  57  87

print()
```

After using df.drop():

```
print(df.drop([0,1,5,9]))

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2  64  29  65  49  50  99  11  89  52  33
3  96  68  98  41  37  94  21  90  74  68
4  87  23  67  50  76  85  63  37  91  71
5  50   4  60  62  72  76  61  11  93  30
6  21  18  62  34  15  72  85  31  62  66
7  57  18  40  25  10  30  35  62  73  43
8   1  89  75  25  84  11  82  36  98  58
9  78  49  46  52   8  84   2  29  57  87
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting rows or columns? What do you mean it would allow you to delete?

```
# Delete Rows by Index Range
df1=df.drop(df.index[2:])
```

Are you looking for a filter condition among the data? Like using window partition function [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/)

Comment: I tried the following: data_test = data_test_prepared.drop(data_test_prepared.index[91, 27, 28, 59, 158, 175, 80, 40]) but got the error IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 8 were indexed

Comment: Try this: data_test = data_test_prepared.drop([data_test_prepared.index[91], data_test_prepared.index[27], data_test_prepared.index[28], data_test_prepared.index[59], data_test_prepared.index[158], data_test_prepared.index[175], data_test_prepared.index[80], data_test_prepared.index[40]])